# Parsing JSON with column key in first array

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I want to parse a JSON string in java and get the following values from the text mentioned below:

```
{
  "columns": [
    "id",
    "name"
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "124",
      "LOREM"
    ],
    [
      "125",
      "DOLOR"
    ],
    [
      "126",
      "FUGIAT"
    ],
    [
      "127",
      "IPSUM"
    ]
 ]
}
```

From every element, i want to get the value from array marked as rows. How do i do this in Jackson JSON for android?

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far. Then we can help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
 List<String> rowsValues = new ArrayList<>(); // to store row String values in List
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data); //data is your json in String format
        JSONArray array =  json.getJSONArray("rows");

        for (int index = 0 ; index < array.length(); index++) {
            JSONArray currentArray = array.getJSONArray(index);
            for (int i = 0 ; i < currentArray.length(); i++) {
                rowsValues.add(array.getString(i));
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```